# horizontal smooth scrolling between div id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

can someone please write me some javaScript to smooth scroll horizontally between the #id's I have ? I have looked and previous questions that have been answered and copied/pasted the answers but they dont seem to work.

Here is relevant HTML -

```
    <div class = option1> <a href="#point1">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class = page2>
       <div class='land7'>
          <img src='images/land7.png'>
     </div>
        <div class="option2">
           <a href="#point2">
             <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           </a>
       </div> 
    <div class='option3'>
      <a href="#point3">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
   </div>
    <div id = point1> </div>
      <div id='point4'> </div>
   </div> 
     <div class="page3">
         <div class='land8'>
             <img src='images/land8.png'>
     </div>
        <div class='option4'>
           <a href="#point4">
             <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
               </a>
         <div id='point3'> </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Google.com type "jquery smooth scroll" first result will be good !!!

Comment: gave it ago - it made my links static. didnt go anywhere